# SQL Server Multiple cascade sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, cascade, cascading-deletes

Assume Table A has two children tables, B and C with cascade delete between A-B, and cascade delete between A-C.

When a row is deleted in A, the matching rows from B and C are deleted.

How does SQL Server determine the order of the Cascades to fire? What I need is to fire the A-C cascade delete before the A-B cascade delete fires.

I know I can do this with triggers, but I don't want to, unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: You don't need CASCADE DELETE or triggers - just process proper order in a stored procedure.

Comment: With cascading delete's, you have no control over the order in which they're being executed, but neither do you have any control over the order in which multiple triggers of the same type are executed.

Answer (score 4):

If the order is that important, this is a database design smell and it also points to the fact that you probably should not be using cascading deletes for this data integrity operation.